# Core Data: "Store in External Record File" vs "Allows External Storage"

Tags: core-data

I actually have a few questions related to Core Data entity attribute settings on iOS:

1. Is "Store in External Record File" for Spotlight integration only?
2. Is "Store in External Record File" for Mac OS only?
3. On the iOS Simulator, where exactly are "External Record Files" stored?

These questions are not to be confused with the Binary Data attribute setting "Allows External Storage". I understand that setting will put data >1MB outside the store.

1. On the iOS Simulator, where are "Allows External Storage" stored?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is described (in detail) in the **Configuring the Model** section of [Core Data Spotlight Integration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SpotlightCoreData/Articles/recordLevel.html):

> To enable Spotlight indexing, you need to specify which properties of
>   which entities should be indexed and which—if any—of those properties
>   should be added to the external record.
>
> In Configuration inspector, for each of the properties that you want
>   to be indexed, select:
>
> Index in Spotlight (Optional) Store in external record file Provided
>   that at least one property for an entity has the “Index in Spotlight”
>   flag set, then whenever a change to an instance of that entity is
>   committed to the persistent store, the corresponding external record
>   file is updated (minimally the last modification date changed). This
>   means that the Spotlight importer will run and so the Spotlight index
>   will be updated with new data.
>
> If you only choose “Index in Spotlight,” Core Data just creates a
>   zero-length file for the corresponding record. If you also select
>   “Store in External Record”, the property is added to the contents of
>   the external record. Simple types, such as strings, dates, and
>   numbers, are exported directly; relationships are stored as UUIDs.

AFAICT:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Doesn't really apply

Comment: Hi Daniel, Yeah I've previously read that guide and wonder if it is telling the complete picture.  I suppose the more important question is "On the iOS Simulator, where are "Allows External Storage" stored?"

Comment: "Allows External Storage" has nothing to do with "Store in External Record File". Those are two entirely separate things. "Allows External Storage" tells Core Data it can store large blobs of data in a file in stead of inside the database. "Store in External Record File" is about letting Spotlight pick up what's inside your db. Spotlight doesn't do that on iOS, only on the Mac. "Allows External Storage" is part of your model. The "external" files are stored next to the db file.

Comment: This blog post, [Core Data: don’t store large files as binary data](https://medium.com/@alexedge/binary-attributes-and-migration-in-core-data-bc7cfb3029fc), says the external files are stored in .YourAppName_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA, presumably under the documents folder.